How to Duplicate faces and scale mirror/flip at the same time using shortcuts only?
Can anyone please let me know how can we quickly mirror / flip any part of the object and place it at the exact opposite but using shortcuts only? (Without Symmetry or Modifiers)

I know this process:

Duplicate the selected faces using SHIFT + D
Press S for scale, then Changing Y-axis value to -1,
Then move selected part manually (or using snaps) to the desired location.

I want to be able to do that quickly, hitting shortcuts only, as you can see in the following video at 3:45
https://youtu.be/AhiUGykR_X0?t=225

If you have the 3D cursor set on the line you want to pivot around, the Object's origin set to the 3D cursor and the Transform Pivot Point on the top toolbar set to 3D cursor, your shortcut sequence should do exactly what you want without having to move anything afterwards. It does look as if the scaling direction has been omitted from the Screencast key sequence on his video.

I was just going to comment the same. I'm not in the mood to watch the whole tutorial to see if he explains more about his initial setup, but the mouse geometry he's creating os centered on the 3D cursor and he has set the Transform Pivot Point to the 3D cursor. So whatever he scales will be scaled from or towards the cursor. I do not know why he's not simply using a Mirror modifier for all that... well, anyway.

I was able to do this all with shortcuts after setting the Pivot Point to 3D Cursor. Thank you both!

Setting the transform orientation to Active Element is also useful because you can just click a single vert in your selection to make it active, functioning basically as a mini-cursor on the fly.

@Jakemoyo Yes, definitely. It's just that he wondered how to do it like in the tutorial. Of course there are other ways too, like just using a Mirror modifier (with several options of mirror axes/objects as well) since it was completely symmetrical.
